# (pytest) Run one test against several environmental variable configurations

Tags: testing, environment-variables, keras, pytest

Is it possible to run tests with pytest such that some specific tests are run against different settings of an environmental variable?

My usecase is as follows: some of my tests use a machine learning library called Keras, but the backend of Keras can either be "Theano", "Tensorflow" or "CNTK". To change the backend I have to set the environmental variable "KERAS_BACKEND" accordingly **before** importing Keras. As a result, I'd like to run the test against those three different settings of the env variable.